# Как реализовать поиск в приложении с помощью retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Всем привет, у меня есть приложение, которое получает и отображает последние фотографии с сайта Unsplash, я хотел реализовать поиск, но почему то приложение падает, не понимаю почему ошибка, помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Мой код:

```
public class PhotoGalleryFragment extends Fragment implements PhotoGridAdapter.ClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PhotoGalleryFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView photosRecyclerView;
    private PhotoOverlayDialog dialog;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private String mSearchObject;


    public static  PhotoGalleryFragment newInstance(int page) {
        PhotoGalleryFragment photoGalleryFragment = new PhotoGalleryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("photogallery", page);
        photoGalleryFragment.setArguments(args);
        return new PhotoGalleryFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_photo_search, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            //Здесь поиск, query передается в GET запрос

                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Query Text Submit: " + query);
                mSearchObject = query;

                new SearchItems().execute();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "QueryTextChange: " + s);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        new FetchItemsTask().execute();
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo_gallery, container, false);
        photosRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.photos);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), App.SPAN_COUNT);
        photosRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        photosRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page) {
                new FetchItemsTask().execute(page);
            }

            @Override
            public void displayLoadingIndicator() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Loading images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new FetchItemsTask().execute();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    private void setAdapter(List<Photo> items) {
        if (photosRecyclerView.getAdapter() == null) {
            photosRecyclerView.setAdapter(new PhotoGridAdapter(items, this));
        } else {
            ((PhotoGridAdapter) photosRecyclerView.getAdapter()).addItems(items);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v, Photo p) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            dialog = PhotoOverlayDialog.newInstance(p);
            dialog.show(fm, "fragment_photo_overlay");
    }


    private class FetchItemsTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Photo>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Photo> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String storedAccessToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_ACCESS_TOKEN), null);
            UnsplashClient restClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(UnsplashClient.class, App.API_BASE_URL, storedAccessToken);
            // default page value
            int page = 1;
            if (params.length > 0) {
                page = params[0];
            }

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * FETCHING PHOTOS PAGE:" + page);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * ACCESS TOKEN:" + storedAccessToken);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * REFRESH TOKEN:" + sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), null));

            Call<List<Photo>> call = restClient.getPhotos(page);
            try {
                Response<List<Photo>> response = call.execute();
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Headers headers = response.headers();
                    Set<String> names = headers.names();
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NAMES:" + headers.names().size());
                    for (String name : names) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NAME:" + name);
                    }
                    Log.i("* * *", "X-Ratelimit-Limit:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Limit"));
                    Log.i("* * *", "X-Ratelimit-Remaining:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Remaining"));
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * END");
                    return response.body();
                }

                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "* * * ERROR FETCHING PHOTOS " + response.code() + "-" + response.message());
                Headers headers = response.headers();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "X-Ratelimit-Limit:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Limit"));
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "X-Ratelimit-Remaining:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Remaining"));

                // access_token expires or access revoked!!!!
                if (response.code() == 401) {
                    // access_token has expired
                    String refreshToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), null);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "* * * USING REFRESH TOKEN:" + refreshToken);
                    OAuthClient oauthClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(OAuthClient.class, App.AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL);
                    Call<AccessToken> oauthCall = oauthClient.refreshToken(App.CLIENT_ID, App.CLIENT_SECRET,
                            refreshToken, "refresh_token");
                    Response<AccessToken> oauthRefreshResponse = oauthCall.execute();
                    if (oauthRefreshResponse.isSuccess()) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = oauthRefreshResponse.body();
                        // Saving access token to Shared Preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_ACCESS_TOKEN), accessToken.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), accessToken.getRefreshToken());
                        editor.commit();
                        restClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(UnsplashClient.class,
                                App.API_BASE_URL, accessToken.getAccessToken());
                        call = restClient.getPhotos(page);
                        response = call.execute();
                        if (response.isSuccess()) {
                            return response.body();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // access has been revoked
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Seems like access to Unsplah has been revoked");
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())
                                .sendBroadcast(new Intent(getResources()
                                        .getString(R.string.INTENT_SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE))
                                        .putExtra("message", R.string.msg_authorization_revoked));
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error requesting Unsplash API: " + e.getMessage());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())
                        .sendBroadcast(new Intent(getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.INTENT_SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE))
                                .putExtra("message", R.string.msg_authorization_error));
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Photo> photos) {
            super.onPostExecute(photos);
            if (photos != null && !photos.isEmpty()) {
                setAdapter(photos);
            }
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }



    private class SearchItems extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, List<Photo>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Photo> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String storedAccessToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_ACCESS_TOKEN), null);
            UnsplashClient restClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(UnsplashClient.class, App.API_BASE_URL, storedAccessToken);
            // default page value
            int page = 1;
            if (params.length > 0) {
                page = params[0];
            }

            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * FETCHING PHOTOS PAGE:" + page);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * ACCESS TOKEN:" + storedAccessToken);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * REFRESH TOKEN:" + sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), null));

            Call<List<Photo>> call = restClient.getSearchPhoto(mSearchObject,page);
            try {
         //Здесь приложение падает
                Response<List<Photo>> response = call.execute();
                if (response.isSuccess()) {
                    Headers headers = response.headers();
                    Set<String> names = headers.names();
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NAMES:" + headers.names().size());
                    for (String name : names) {
                        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "NAME:" + name);
                    }
                    Log.i("* * *", "X-Ratelimit-Limit:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Limit"));
                    Log.i("* * *", "X-Ratelimit-Remaining:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Remaining"));
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "* * * END");
                    return response.body();
                }

                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "* * * ERROR FETCHING PHOTOS " + response.code() + "-" + response.message());
                Headers headers = response.headers();
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "X-Ratelimit-Limit:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Limit"));
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "X-Ratelimit-Remaining:" + headers.get("X-Ratelimit-Remaining"));

                // access_token expires or access revoked!!!!
                /*if (response.code() == 401) {
                    // access_token has expired
                    String refreshToken = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), null);
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "* * * USING REFRESH TOKEN:" + refreshToken);
                    OAuthClient oauthClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(OAuthClient.class, App.AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL);
                    Call<AccessToken> oauthCall = oauthClient.refreshToken(App.CLIENT_ID, App.CLIENT_SECRET,
                            refreshToken, "refresh_token");
                    Response<AccessToken> oauthRefreshResponse = oauthCall.execute();
                    if (oauthRefreshResponse.isSuccess()) {
                        AccessToken accessToken = oauthRefreshResponse.body();
                        // Saving access token to Shared Preferences
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_ACCESS_TOKEN), accessToken.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putString(getString(R.string.ACCESS_TOKEN_FILE_REFRESH_TOKEN), accessToken.getRefreshToken());
                        editor.commit();
                        restClient = ServiceGenerator.createService(UnsplashClient.class,
                                App.API_BASE_URL, accessToken.getAccessToken());
                        call = restClient.getPhotos(page);
                        response = call.execute();
                        if (response.isSuccess()) {
                            return response.body();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // access has been revoked
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Seems like access to Unsplah has been revoked");
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())
                                .sendBroadcast(new Intent(getResources()
                                        .getString(R.string.INTENT_SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE))
                                        .putExtra("message", R.string.msg_authorization_revoked));
                        startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class));
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                }*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error requesting Unsplash API: " + e.getMessage());
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext())
                        .sendBroadcast(new Intent(getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.INTENT_SHOW_TOAST_MESSAGE))
                                .putExtra("message", R.string.msg_authorization_error));
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Photo> photos) {
            super.onPostExecute(photos);
            if (photos != null && !photos.isEmpty()) {
                setAdapter(photos);
            }
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }

}
```

В UnsplashClient:

```
public interface UnsplashClient {

    @GET("/photos?per_page=30")
    Call<List<Photo>> getPhotos(@Query("page") int page);

    @GET("/search/photos")
    Call<List<Photo>> getSearchPhoto(@Query("query") String query,
                                     @Query("page") int page);

}
```

Ошибка:

```
02-05 14:28:35.557 384-702/ru.mypackage.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: ru.mypackage.name, PID: 384
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:822)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
    at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36)
    at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24)
    at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148)
    at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116)
    at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at ru.mypackage.name.fragment.PhotoGalleryFragment$SearchItems.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:260)
    at ru.mypackage.name.fragment.PhotoGalleryFragment$SearchItems.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:810)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775) 
    at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:36) 
    at retrofit.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:24) 
    at retrofit.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:148) 
    at retrofit.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:116) 
    at retrofit.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:61) 
    at ru.mypackage.name.fragment.PhotoGalleryFragment$SearchItems.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:260) 
    at ru.mypackage.name.fragment.PhotoGalleryFragment$SearchItems.doInBackground(PhotoGalleryFragment.java:242) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
02-05 14:28:35.724 384-433/ru.mypackage.name E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f5f4d91d7a0
```

Comment: BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472529/expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array-at-line-1-column-2-path

Comment: @V.March, а чего всё остальное не исправил? А то буду отклонять такие правки.

Comment: @V.March, речь только об этом вопросе и правку утвердил я, но нажатием ["Принять и править"](//ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/176658), после чего отформатировал код в вопросе - там были бросающиеся в глаза огромные отступы у исключения, а у двух блоков кода последняя фигурная скобка в эти блоки не попадала. Пока твои правки проходят проверки через очередь (у тебя меньше 2000 репутации) стоит стараться исправлять сразу все недочёты, а не некоторые.

Comment: @Qwertiy. понял, буду смотреть более глобально на весь вопрос. Спасибо за правку и детальное разъяснение. А можно эти коменты-диалог удалить из поста - они здесь не совсем кместу.

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в парсинге `json`. Посмотрите на то какой `json` вам отдает сервер и посмотрите какая структура у вашего объекта. Где-то полем может ошиблись. 
Вот [сайт](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) на котором можно сделать объект по `json`